# Difference between 日 and 一日

Tags: grammar, time

What is the difference between 日{ひ｝ and 一日｛いちにち}?
I thought that 一日 was used when refering to the **length** of a day but I saw this sentence and got confused:

> 今朝のニュースでも、アナウンサーの人が「うららかな**一日**になるでしょう」って言ってたよ。
>
> Also, on the news this morning the announcer said that it would probably become a beautiful day.

Why is it correct to use 一日 rather than 日 here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a day is quite ambiguous in any language and Japanese is no exception. A day can be: 24 hours, a calendar day, a period between sunrise and sunset, a period between you wake up and go to sleep, one's workday. One day might have more than 24 hours (長い一日だった), the other less...

That said 一日{いちにち} in your example refers to a time period that someone perceived or might perceive as a "beautiful day". It is essentially 一日間 here and although using it would be unnatural, it would probably be grammatical.

Like in 忙しい一日でした the 間 is absent, but if you extended the period to two weeks you would say 忙しい2週間でした.

日{ひ} on the other hand has more of a "calendar day" or an "exemplary day" feeling to it. うららかな日は外で遊びます。

Answer (score 2):

一日 means either the first day of the month or one day, but can also mean all day.

In that context, 一日 is used to denote that the **whole** day will be beautiful.

Anyone please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still learning myself.

Comment: tsuitachi = first day of the month but Ichinichi means "[that] one [entire] day" .. you're right =)

Comment: At work you can say「今日も一日宜しくお願いします」 but hopefully it refers only to business hours... ;)

Comment: So would it be incorrect to change 一日 to 日？